# How to redirect to child route and redirect again in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I'm working on an Angular 5 application that doesn't have a root `/` route. It should redirect to one of the lazy loaded children. Each child module has its own redirect from `/child` to `/child/view` (where the word "child" is the name of the feature).

The idea is that the root routes don't know where the default route is for a child. So I can just redirect to the preferred child module, and let that child handle the final redirect. So there should be two redirects.

Here is my root `MainRoutes.ts` file:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/posts', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {
        path: '', component: MainComponent,
        children: [
            {path: 'albums', loadChildren: 'app/Albums/Albums#AlbumsModule'},
            {path: 'todos', loadChildren: 'app/Todos/Todos#TodosModule'},
            {path: 'posts', loadChildren: 'app/Posts/Posts#PostsModule'},
            {path: 'users', loadChildren: 'app/Users/Users#UsersModule'}
        ]
    },
    {path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MainRoutesModule {
}
```

My main routes above should redirect the `/` root path to the `/posts` child route, but it's redirecting to `/albums` instead. I can't tell if the problem is in my main routes definitions or my child routes.

Here is my `AlbumsRoutes.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/albums/view', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'view', component: ViewComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AlbumsRoutesModule {
}
```

I also have `TodosModule`, `PostsModule` and `UsersModule` which are the same as above (except with different names).

I wrote the above that way because I think the `forChild` routes are relative to where they are loaded.

When I go to `/` the URL is redirect to `/albums/view`. It seems like the redirect defined in my root isn't being used. I need it to redirect to `/posts/view`.

The fact that it goes to `/albums/view` tells me that the routes for the first child are being used.

I know I've made a simple mistake, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think redirectTo only works for routes on the same level.

You may try this instead

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/posts', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {
    path: 'albums',
    component: MainComponent,
    loadChildren: 'app/Albums/Albums#AlbumsModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'posts',
    component: MainComponent,
    loadChildren: 'app/Posts/Posts#PostsModule'
  },
  ...
  {path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent}
];
```